# full screen image on webpage is squashed when device is rotated only from portrait to landscape

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, landscape-portrait

Image displays fine (covers entire background) in portrait on devices, but when rotated to landscape the image is squashed. This only happens if it is initially loaded as portrait; if the site is loaded in landscape orientation initially, it displays fine as you rotate between landscape and portrait. The rest of my site is unaffected.

Here's a fiddle of just the image: http://jsfiddle.net/pauljackson/66sqz/

And my site: http://wabi-sabi.cc

html:

```
<body>
<div class="slide-wrapper">
    <div class="full-video-wrapper">
        <img src="http://www.wabi-sabi.cc/test/images/wabisabiwebvideo.jpg" id="bgimg" alt="Full Screen Image">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; }

.slide-wrapper {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.full-video-wrapper {
background: white;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: 1;
overflow: hidden;
}
#bgimg {
height:100%;
width:auto;
margin:0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's all the CSS involved? The fiddle behaves differently than the actual site.

Comment: Yes, it does behave differently but in ways that do not effect my issue; it occurs in the fiddle just as it does on my site. You have to open it up in a device (I am using an iPad mini).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use something like this:

```
tag { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This will cover the area but won't (supposedly) squash your image. Note also; the background-size function imho is the best way to go; there are many different settings you could see them here:
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however in this scenario the image does not fill the entire screen, it simply displays at its original resolution, fixed. On an ipad screen that means a lot of white space underneath the image.

Comment: the cover won't give you white space contain will; the background-size: cover; will ultimately cover your area, the stated way; center center; will display the center of the image. Please read more here about it:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover

Comment: The fixed doesn't matter; thats an example I gave you; you need to build it upon your personal needs.

Comment: alright, I tried implementing this but for some reason the background just goes white now at 980px, no image. see here: http://wabi-sabi.cc/test

Comment: (btw i added single quotes around the image url in the brackets)

Comment: Did you properly state your background image URL?

Comment: The problem is here:

http://wabi-sabi.cc/test/css/images/wabisabiwebvideo.jpg

Not found

Comment: In other words; your source for the background image is invalid. -

Comment: oh good catch, thanks. I changed it to the actual ../images/wabisabiwebvideo.jpg and unfortunately still no dice.

Comment: Still not working, the image isn't correctly directed. where is your image? and whats the name and extension?

Comment: Ok working now, the image is OK, now:

background-image: url("");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

Try using that manner of code; so we could easily see whats wrong and not.

Comment: Alright I adjusted it. Still nothing showing up. This is perplexing, thank you for your assistance!

Comment: try adding: width: 100%; and height: 100%; to the tag.

Comment: Genius! It's working great! Thank you so much belthazorNv, you are a life saver.

Comment: You're welcome :) make sure to adjust the centerdiv, to stay at the middle of the screen when you resize the page..